# Comparing two two-dimensional probability distributions

Tags: distributions, kullback-leibler, bhattacharyya

I would like to compare two contour plots representing two probability distributions. These are not samples drawn from any known distribution, but the result of a physical calculation from a process in an atom. In particular, I would like to know how similar these two distributions are to quantitatively answer questions such as: "how much overlap is there between these two distributions?", "to what extent do they occupy the same regions of the (x,y) plane?", "how similar is the intensity (amplitude) of the distributions in regions of the (x,y) plane?".

I have read about the KL divergence, and the Bhattacharya distance however the Bhattacharya distance seems to assume an underlying normal distribution? And the KL divergence is asymmetric so I am unsure how useful it is for this purpose. They also seem to be suitable for samples drawn from distributions rather than for comparing distributions themselves.

I have also attempted the following: obtained the (x, y) coordinates where the intensity is greater than a particular value (the brightest features of the map) and then binning the x-values to form a histogram. The same is done for y-values. This gives me two histograms along the axes, for both distributions for which I calculated the Bhattacharya distance, correlation etc. But physically, I am not sure if this makes much sense at all?

I am very new to statistics so any general terms for which to search for related to this would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with this question is that you haven't provided any information to answer it: please tell us *what kind of comparison* would be relevant to your application.  It is strange that you do describe some comparisons in the first paragraph but then you abandon them for speculation about unrelated techniques.  This sounds more like it's a physics problem than a statistical one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance may be helpful.

Comment: @whuber any sort of quantitative comparison to answer the questions in the first paragraph would be useful at this point. I am totally lacking the resources (and knowledge) to even know what to search for to address this problem - the techniques in the second paragraph are what come up when I search how to compare distributions.

Comment: You might find the quantum mechanical literature to be more relevant and useful.

Comment: @whuber do you mean entropy and such? Can I ask why the KL divergence/Bhattacharya distance are not suitable for this purpose?

Comment: I can't tell you because you haven't clearly stated any purpose--you have only proposed a bunch of very different ways of comparing distributions.  What I can say is that having extensive experience with probability calculations of atomic structures, I never had any use for these divergences or distances -- but I might have been interested in different phenomena than you are.

Comment: @whuber Ok- I see what you mean now by "purpose". Here is some context on the problem: I have obtained a correlated two-electron momentum distribution following a physical process in the atom involving excitation to a particular energy level. The energy level strongly affects the shape of the distribution, as well as the intensity of the maxima. This process can involve excitation to several different energy levels, all of whom give different shapes of the distribution, depending on their quantum numbers. I want to quantify, in some useful way, how similar these distributions are.

Comment: These distributions can also be combined - I would like to know "how much" each of the individual distributions contribute to the final map.

Comment: Are you looking at isolated atoms?  If so, your comparison must be invariant to orthogonal rotations of the distributions around the center of mass, which is an interesting twist (so to speak...)  Your question about combinations isn't really clear.  After all, such combinations typically are additive, which means there isn't much of an issue about how much each contributes to the total.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151895/discussion-between-lethobentho-and-whuber).